# Print items from a list that have been filtered through a function

Tags: python

I'm given a list of names:

```
names=['Liam','Noah',3,'Oliver',10.5,'William','Elijah',"33",'James',True,'Benjamin','Lucas',"22.0",'Mason','Ethan', 'Olivia', False, 'Emma', 'Ava', 'Sophia', 'Isabella', None, 'Charlotte', 'Amelia', 'Mia', 'Harper', 'Evelyn']
```

Then, For each element in the list "names", I have to test whether these are true strings or not and print: Welcome to this world "name"

I enter this code and get these [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn39O.png)

But I'm not sure how to print this list without "None" showing up. Pls help.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image

Comment: What do you notice about all the values that translate to `None`?  Why would those code paths return `None` from your function?

Comment: "33" **is** a true string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
names=['Liam','Noah',3,'Oliver',10.5,'William','Elijah',"33",'James',True,'Benjamin','Lucas',"22.0",'Mason','Ethan', 'Olivia', False, 'Emma', 'Ava', 'Sophia', 'Isabella', None, 'Charlotte', 'Amelia', 'Mia', 'Harper', 'Evelyn']
def string_sort(x):
    try:
      a = float(x)
      return a
    except:
      return(f"welcome to this world {x.upper()}!")


for name in names:
  if type(name) == str:
    if type(string_sort(name)) == float:
      continue
    print(string_sort(name))
  else:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the function you entire list and store the resulting f-strings in another list, which you return:

```
def string_sort(lst):
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) == str:
            try:
                float(item)
                continue
            except ValueError:
                result.append(f"Welcome to this world {item.upper()}!")
    return result

for x in string_sort(names):
    print(x)
```